# Best way to display camera video stream in modern OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, video, video-streaming, augmented-reality

I'm creating an augmented reality application in OpenGL where I want to augment a video stream captured by a Kinect with virtual objects. I found some running code using fixed function pipeline OpenGL that creates a `glTexImage2D`, fills it with the image data and then creates a `GL_QUAD` with `glTexCoord2f` to fill the screen.

I'm looking for an optimized solution using modern, shader-based OpenGL only which is also capable of handling HD video streams.

I guess what I hope for as an answer to my question is a list of possibilities on how rendering a camera video stream can be achieved in OpenGL from which I can select the one that best fits my needs.

Comment: PBO (pixel buffer object) are used for streamed textures. Also some modern hardware has the ability to stream video capture directly to GPU memory (GPUDirect for NVIDIA, but there's maybe other solutions)

Comment: thanks for your reply! I've read about PBO's in combination with textures and it seems this is a pretty efficient solution! But as far as I understand it, PBO's are only used for pixel-transfer to the GPU. Is there another way of rendering the video image than storing them in a texture?

Comment: A texture is just an OpenGL abstraction for an N-dimensional array of colors with some filtering options available.  What other conceivable type would you want it to be on the OpenGL side?

Comment: Thanks! Using a texture is certainly the most obvious way of doing it. How about shader storage buffer objects? Another follow-up question: I recently read about `image` variables that can be used instead of a `sampler` in my shader to access the pixel data. What are the major differences between those two?

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Image_variables